# MySQL read only error but permissions set and SELinux AFAICT correct

Tags: centos, permissions, mysql

I am new to MySQL and Linux and because I had issues with an old MySQL version (5.1) I used mysqldump and installed MySQL 5.6. I changed the datadir location by copying everything to the new folder and set a symbolic link in the default directory to my new folder. I set the permissions to 755 and the user und group is mysql. With ls -aZ I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x. mysql    mysql    unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

The exact error messages are:

1. with `mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=new_dir`:

   ```
   [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.24 started; log sequence number 1600717
   ERROR: 1036  Table 'db' is read only
   [ERROR] Aborting
   ```
2. in `/var/log/mysqld.log` I found:

   ```
   [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
   [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'user' is read only`
   ```

But I can't run `mysql_upgrade` because mysql is not running. I always get:

```
    MySQL Daemon failed to start.
    Starting mysqld:  [FAILED]
```

when trying: `service mysqld start`

If you have any suggestions how to solve this, please let me know. They are very appreciated!

UPDATE:
Thanks to apaul for the suggestions!

1. I installed the repository for `yum` and then further installed mysql by `yum`.
2. I only copied the mysql folder and the ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 files and performance-scheme which appeared after mysql installation. Because I didn't dumped and didn't deleted the mysql folder in contrast to my real data databases. As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456159/how-to-shrink-purge-ibdata1-file-in-mysql).
3. I already use the `--datadir` as well as `--user=mysq`l when performing `mysql_install_db` command.
4. All directories for mysql are 755 so should be executable. But I think - as I remember correct -  it was only 700 before the change to 5.6.

What I also tested: restarting the PC and I tried in the my.cnf the real path to the datadir and the path to the symlink.

Comment: Did you installed mysql 5.6 with `yum` or have you compiled it yourself? If you have a dump of your database, you should import it rather than trying to copy its datafiles. When running `mysql_install_db`, use a full path for `--datadir` and ensure your `mysql` user can access it (ie. all parents directories should have at least the `x` permission for that user.